# How to GROUP BY same value in different rows with condition? (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have this table:

```
+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
| id        | member_id | date                |
+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
| 1         |     2     | 2020-07-27 21:53:46 |
| 2         |     1     | 2020-07-27 22:03:58 |
| 3         |     1     | 2020-07-27 22:09:16 |
| 4         |     1     | 2020-07-27 22:11:33 |
| 5         |     2     | 2020-07-27 22:12:21 |
-----------------------------------------------
```

And I would like to `GROUP BY` something like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
| id        | member_id | date                |
+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
| 1         |     2     | 2020-07-27 21:53:46 |
| 2         |     1     | 2020-07-27 22:03:58 |
| 5         |     2     | 2020-07-27 22:12:21 |
-----------------------------------------------
```

But when I put `GROUP BY member_id` it just return me two rows (1, 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand this as a gaps-and-island problem, where you want to display the rows whose `member_id` is different than the "previous" row.

Here is an approach using window functions (available in MySQL 8.0): `lag()` gives the `member_id` on the previous row, that we can then compare to the value on the current row:

```
select id, member_id, date
from (
    select t.*, lag(member_id) over(order by date) lag_member_id
    from mytable t
) t
where not lag_member_id <=> member_id 
order by date
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f8e4679b1722d8fc2c845c6c3d8745a7)**:

```
id | member_id | date               
-: | --------: | :------------------
 1 |         2 | 2020-07-27 21:53:46
 2 |         1 | 2020-07-27 22:03:58
 5 |         2 | 2020-07-27 22:12:21
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I coded a little bit different cos Im using an old version of MySQL, but it worked! Its a nice idea comparing the previous row.